# Migrating from glassfish 3.1.1 to 4.1 causing java.lang.IllegalStateException error

Tags: java-8, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4.1

While trying to migrate from glassfish 3.1.1 to 4.1 I am getting following error:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:705)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getAttributes(FacesContextImpl.java:237)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.setInstance(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:55)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.release(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:64)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.release(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.release(FacesContextImpl.java:591)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:53)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:665)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>Info:   visiting unvisited references
```

The application deployed successfully and but did not run in browser.

Maven Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

glassfish lib directory jars image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOdD.png

browser image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPBQZ.png

Previously I was using JDK 7 and Glassfish 3.1.1 . Now I am trying to migrate to JDK 8 and glassfish 4.1. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution. I am using netbeans 8.1 and MySQL as my database. I am using JPA.

Comment: So it worksf you use java 7 with this new glassfish version?

Comment: Try removing the `com.sun.faces` dependencies. They are bundled with GlassFish. And 4.1 is old, I would advise a newer version and / or consider switching to Payara.

Comment: @Kukeltje No glassfish 4.1 requires jdk 8.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I tried removing **com.sun.faces** dependencies and added following dependency:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

but didn't worked. I tried payara server also but some backward compatibility issues came. Currently I want it to run in glassfish 4.1 server for development purpose. Do you have any solution?